# C# Login XML looping wrong password

Tags: c#, xml, loops, streamreader

I have small issue with C# and loading from XML files. (just a notice - student project)

I am making login form with XML, and If there is only one account in XML file this works just fine, but if there are more accounts, If I select any other than the first one program will load one account and then loop X amount times and say "Wrong username or password"

```
    public static bool Login(bool UserExists)
{
    string sUsername;
    string sPassword;
    string check;
    int nPick;

    Console.WriteLine("Insert username: ");
    sUsername = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Insert password: ");
    sPassword = Console.ReadLine();

    List<User> lUser = GetUsers();
    for (int i = 0; i < lUser.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (lUser[i].username == sUsername && lUser[i].password == sPassword)
        {
            UserExists = true;
            Console.WriteLine("\n Login successfull!");
            do
            {
                Menu();
                check = Console.ReadLine();
                int.TryParse(check, out nPick);
                switch (nPick)
                {
                    case 1:

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        break;
                    case 4:

                        break;
                    case 5:
                        System.Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n Option not existing!");
                        break;
                }
            }
            while (nPick != 5);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Wrong username or password!\n");
        }
    }
    return UserExists; 
} 

    public static List<User> GetUsers() {
        List<User> lUser = new List<User>();
        string sXml = "";
        StreamReader oSr = new StreamReader("X");
        using (oSr)
        {
            sXml = oSr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        XmlDocument oXml = new XmlDocument();
        oXml.LoadXml(sXml);
        XmlNodeList oNodes = oXml.SelectNodes("//data/user");
        foreach (XmlNode oNode in oNodes)
        {
            string u = oNode["username"].InnerText;
            string p = oNode["password"].InnerText;
            User oUser = new User(u, p); lUser.Add(oUser);
        }
        return lUser;
    }
```

EDIT1: Added XML

```
<data>
  <user>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>user</password>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>user1</username>
    <password>user1</password>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>user2</username>
    <password>user2</password>
  </user>
</data>
```

For example

1) If I enter "admin" "admin" combination, program will proceed into menu

2) If I enter "user1" "user1" it will login, but also write three times "Wrong username/password"

Comment: give a sample of your xml, and a sample of your input (how are you entering the username and password on the console for single and multiple users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to the answer. You would want to loop through every user and only print the error message if none of those matches.

Note that I also moved the `UserExists` boolean into the function variable instead of having it as a parameter.

```
public static bool Login()
{
    string sUsername;
    string sPassword;
    string check;
    int nPick;
    bool UserExists = false;

    Console.WriteLine("Insert username: ");
    sUsername = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Insert password: ");
    sPassword = Console.ReadLine();

    List<User> lUser = GetUsers();
    for (int i = 0; i < lUser.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (lUser[i].username == sUsername && lUser[i].password == sPassword)
        {
            UserExists = true;
            Console.WriteLine("\n Login successfull!");
            do
            {
                Menu();
                check = Console.ReadLine();
                int.TryParse(check, out nPick);
                switch (nPick)
                {
                    case 1:

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        break;
                    case 4:

                        break;
                    case 5:
                        System.Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n Option not existing!");
                        break;
                }
            }
            while (nPick != 5);
        }
    }
    if (!UserExists) {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Wrong username or password!\n");
    }
    return UserExists; 
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, also moving boolean helped me to compress code a bit, thank you!